# Code Injection in .png file

Tags: c

I am using the libpng- a c library to check the valid .png file. If a file is valid it passes the test. I want to inject shell code in it. How can I craft a .png file, so that it is still a valid image file and also contains some shell code in it. Please tell me how is it possible. Thanks.

Comment: Should the injected shell code be executed?

Comment: Yes, the code wil be executed, but What I want is to keep the image file valid as well.

Comment: @Nate , if the .png file is changed by writing some shell code in it and will become invalid (invalid part is tried), but I want to keep the file valid with some shell code in it. How is that possible, some trick?

Comment: libraries reading .png files will treat the whole .png file as data, even if it is code. So even if you create a valid .png file with shell code inside, it will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, AFAIK there is no way to inject code into a png file and execute it. But you can inject your png file into a shell script, and after view it. But you must convince the one you hack to make the png file executable and to open so-called png file through terminal.

The procedure is:

1. Create a text file, call it `executeme.png`
2. Paste the following code into it, note that there shouldn't be any new line at the end of the file.

- 

```
#!/bin/bash

PNG_FILE=$(mktemp /tmp/hack.XXXXXXX.png)

ARCHIVE=$(awk '/^__ARCHIVE_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0)
tail -n+$ARCHIVE $0 > "$PNG_FILE"

# whatever you want to do is here!

xdg-open $PNG_FILE

exit 0

__ARCHIVE_BELOW__
```

3. Append your original png file using `cat injectme.png >> executeme.png`.
4. Make `executeme.png` executable.
5. If you run the `executeme.png` from terminal, the original png file will be shown using the default image viewer, and your injected code will be run.

Note: I don't believe there is someone so stupid to execute that file.

Note2: On Ubuntu, `executeme.png` cannot be executed from file managers because it's tried to be opened using the file manager due to the png extension. You may rename file `executeme.png` to `execute.\rpng` (append a carriage return before png after dot) so at first it looks like a png file, since its extension is not png it will be executed with double click if it's executable. To make that renaming, you may need to use terminal.

Have a good time hacking! :D

Further reading: [Linux journal, making installers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818)